# difference between animal and plant durring organogenesis

Tags: human-biology

i would like to ask about organogenesis of animals and the relationship with plant as we depends on it. me i do not understand why we are totally different with the plant but all of our body made comes from plant.
please help me to understand

Answer (score 1):

Our development is determined by our genes, encoded in our DNA. This is what makes a human who eats a salad develop differently from a pig, butterfly, or even bacterium eating that same salad.

To understand how all of this works, you can start by studying introductory biology. A nice way to start might be by searching youtube for "introductory high school biology", and selecting a video sponsored by a university. You can also find many free introductory textbooks online.

Then, you will begin to understand the secrets of how life works!